# Textedit(or similar) within Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, text-editor, embedding

Is there a way I can get text-edit or a similar application integrated within my own application. I want the user to edit the documents within my application, so is there someway I can embed text-edit or any other application that allows simple text-editing in my app?
I don't want to write a a text-edit application as it will just simply double (or maybe even more) the work, besides, I don't have time or know where to start, and the budget for the project is really low as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using an `NSTextView` gets you about 85% of the way to having TextEdit embedded in your app. Font changes, find and replace, spell checking,  and undo support are available just by checking a box in IB.

Take a look at Apple's article ["Building a Text Editor In 15 Minutes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/EditorTutorial/TextEditor.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH9-CJBHAJJJ) Hyperbole, perhaps, but I think it will tell you what you need to know.

The source for TextEdit is also available in /Developer/Examples/ for your reading pleasure.